# Saving StripeID to Firestore Collection Document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm switching data from Firebase Realtime Database to Firestore because I need more querying capabilities. However, I'm having trouble with saving my customer's `stripeID` to their collection document. My Cloud Function is hitting perfectly because Stripe is creating the customer correctly, but it's not assigning to the collection reference. What do I need to fix so the collection reference could recognize the `stripeID` as well? Thank you!

**What I'm Seeing**

[image]

[image]

**Customer Model**

```
struct Customer {
    
    let uid: String
    let stripeId: String
    let fullname: String
    let email: String
    let username: String
    let profileImageUrl: String
    
    init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.stripeId = dictionary["stripeId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    
}
```

**AuthServices**

```
struct CustomerCredentials {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let fullname: String
    let username: String
    let profileImage: UIImage
}

static func createCustomer(credentials: CustomerCredentials, completion: CollectionCompletion) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                    
                guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }
                    
                let values = ["uid" : uid,
                              "email" : credentials.email,
                              "fullname" : credentials.fullname,
                              "username" : credentials.username,
                              "profileImageUrl" : profileImageUrl]
                    
                REF_CUSTOMERS.document(uid).setData(values, completion: completion)
            }
    }

}
```

**RegistrationController**

```
@objc func handleCreateAccount() {

    let credentials = CustomerCredentials(email: email, password: password, fullname: fullname,
                                          username: username, profileImage: profileImage)
        
    AuthService.createCustomer(credentials: credentials) { error in
        if let error = error {
            Auth.auth().handleFireAuthError(error: error, vc: self)
            self.showLoader(false)
            return
        }
            
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeCustomer").call(["email" : email]) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do? What have you tried? What error are you having? Currently your code is still using the Realtime Database, you need to update to Firestore syntax (`customersRef.doc(uid).set(data)` etc.)

Comment: I need help figuring out why my stripeID won’t set as a value for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my RegistrationController, I had to add an `updateData` value inside my Cloud Function code snippet in order to add it to my customer reference.

**RegistrationController**

```
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeCustomer").call(["email" : email]) { result, error in
      if let error = error {
          debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
          return
      }
                
      let value = ["stripeId" : result?.data]
                
      guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                
      REF_CUSTOMERS.document(uid).updateData(value as [AnyHashable : Any])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `REF_CUSTOMERS` points to the "customers" collection, then when you're using the following line of code:

```
REF_CUSTOMERS.document(uid).setData(values, completion: completion)
```

For writing the following values:

```
let values = ["uid" : uid,
              "email" : credentials.email,
              "fullname" : credentials.fullname,
              "username" : credentials.username,
              "profileImageUrl" : profileImageUrl]
```

The document that will be added will always contain **only** the data that exists in the `values` object. Since there is no `stripeId` present, the document that will be written will not contain the `stripeId`. If you need to have the `stripeId` as a field in the user document, then you have to add it like this:

```
let values = ["uid" : uid,
              "email" : credentials.email,
              "fullname" : credentials.fullname,
              "username" : credentials.username,
              "profileImageUrl" : profileImageUrl
              "stripeId" : stripeId] //
```

Comment: Hey Zachary. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Where am I getting the `stripeId` value from? Because I have to assign it somewhere to actually save it to the collection document, correct?

Comment: From the exact same place you're already getting it, right? You only need to add to the value object.